# Website broken after change of image on Dreamweaver CS4

Tags: html, dreamweaver, cs4

My website was fine until I changed an image in the template on Dreamweaver CS4 (I know it's old) and all of a sudden, none of the links work and no images are showing.

All the links on the code are showing as  img src="../New Folder/images/Gelec Header2.jpg" and on chrome it says not allowed to load local source.

The website is www.gelec.co.uk for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS, JS and image URLS. Replace all `file://` to `http://www.gelec.co.uk`

Example:

```
<link href="file:///New Folder/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

to

```
<link href="http://www.gelec.co.uk/New Folder/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove `../` from the img URL if you hosting on the web server.

```
img src="New Folder/images/Gelec Header2.jpg"
```

Comment: I've tried that but then the image is removed from dreamweaver

Comment: You want this to work on the dreameaver or web server ?

Comment: The web server. New problem though - I just want to stick a page that says 'new website coming soon'. I uploaded it onto the ftp but nothing has changed (it usually uploads straight away)

Comment: Fine, then you can use redirect option for your default page to show when website loads.

Comment: Can I ask how you do that please? I'm not a coder and so I've been creating a website on go daddy but obviously I broke the current website.. oops!

Comment: Create new html page called comming.html then redirect your URL to comming.html. You can google for Godaddy help site for the procedure.